# iOS Cell TextField Text Size Not Resizing When Scrolling Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I am having an issue when scrolling in a collection view cell.  The text isn't resizing to fit based on the populated value and space available.  In the image that isn't working as expected, I have scrolled down a "page" or 2.  In the set-up below, extraDetail1 seems to scales based on the first scale size of the first cell created.  It appears that when the cell is re-used, the text doesn't resize.  I want "extraDetail1" to reduce font size when needed.  I am even okay if extraDetail1 truncates if that is my only choice.  I don't want the text to overlap.  I prefer to have "extraDetail2" = "$..." not reduce in size, but I am okay if it also reduces similar to extraDetail1 if needed.

```
// cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let actionFigure = headerArray[indexPath.section].sectionActionFigureArray[indexPath.row]

    if isShowPhotoView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: kPhotoCollectionCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionCell
        cell.configureForPhotoCollectionCell(forActionFigure: actionFigure)
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: kDetailCollectionCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DetailCollectionCell
        cell.configureForDetailCollectionCell(forActionFigure: actionFigure, forFigureCondition: ebaySearchConditionSelected)
        return cell
    }
}
```

view layout

[image]

cell setup

[image: cell setup]

configuration

[image: configuration]

what shows up, green is correct, red isn't.  I have the same issue with the other text boxes.  See that the PDT-8 title line runs off too when its too long.

[image]